# Difference on Mongoose using Promise or Async/Await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Using ExpressJs (as Web framework for Node.js) and Mongoose (for modeling MongoDB) to create a web service. I had a question about the best approach to handle the return object from some mongoose methods as (save, find, findByIdAndDelete, etc).

As the mongoose documentation says, the Model.prototype.save() will returns «Promise,undefined» Returns undefined if used with callback or a Promise otherwise.
For more: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save

So i want to know which one should we use or on which case one is better that the other?

As example using ES7 Async/Await:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Person = mongoose.model('person');

module.exports.savePerson = async (req,res) => {
  await new Person( {...req.body} )
    .save( (err, doc)=> {
      err ? res.status(400).json(err) : res.send(doc);
    });
}
```

As example using ES6 Promise:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Person = mongoose.model('person');

module.exports.savePerson = (req,res) => {
  const person = new Person( {...req.body} )

  person.save()
    .then(person => {
      res.send(person);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(400).json(err)
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not promise vs async/await, because async/await is syntactic sugar for promises. This is Mongoose promise vs callback API. Callback API is obsolete. And it certainly shouldn't be used with async/await like in example above

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a callback if you want to `await` it:

```
 module.exports.savePerson = async (req,res) => {
   try {
     const doc = await new Person( {...req.body} ).save();
     res.send(doc);
   } catch(error) {
     res.status(400).json(err);
   }
};
```

> So i want to know should we use [.thens] or [awaits] ?

Thats opinion based, but in my eyes `await` is *way* more readable, especially when you have to wait for multiple things.

---

Security advise: Directly passing the clients data to the database without validation is a bit dangerous.